# Delphi 7, ADO, Reading binary data in BLOB fields in "DBase IV" table. How to disable transliterate?

Tags: delphi, blob, ado, dbase, bde

I'm using Delphi 7 and ADO (TAdoTable component).

I need to read binary data from "DBase IV" table (dbf/dbt) using ADO. Binary data is stored in BLOB fields.

This table was previously created programattically by BDE (TTable component was used). "Transliterate" poperties of BLOB fields were set to false, so binary data in this table is stored with no change, "as is" (I checked this by HexEdit).

And all what I need is to read this binary data with NO TRANSLITERATION.

My steps:

```
Source   : TADOTable;
prepList : TBlobField;
str      : string;
...

Source.Open;  //Open table
prepList:=source.FieldByName('PREPLIST') as TBlobField;  //Get BLOB field
prepList.Transliterate:=false; //No need to transliterate
...

str:=prepList.AsString;  //Reading data
...
```

Data in "str" sometimes differs from what is actually stored. 
For example, I get:

```
$AF $67
```

instead of actual data, as it stored in DBT part of table:

```
$F4 $67
```

When I use BDE and TTable component in absolutely same way (Transliterate:=false) it is OK. But with ADO, in spite of Transliterate value, it always transliterates data. Same result can be achived with BDE also, if set Transliterate to true.

Maybe I need to set some parameters in ConnectionString?

I tried these ConnectionStrings (%s - path to table directory):

```
//Using provider JET 4.0
cConnectionString=
'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'+
'User ID=Admin;'+
'Data Source=%s;'+
'Mode=Share Deny None;'+
'Extended Properties=DBASE IV;'+
'Jet OLEDB:System database="";'+
'Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";'+
'Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";'+
'Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=17;'+
'Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;'+
'Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;'+
'Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;'+
'Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";'+
'Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;'+
'Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;'+
'Jet OLEDB:Don''t Copy Locale on Compact=False;'+
'Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;'+
'Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;';

//Using ODBC driver
cConnectionString=
'Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};'+
'DriverID=277;'+
'Dbq=%s;';
```

Both ways - same result.

How make ADO not to transliterate binary data in BLOB fields?

UPDATE:
I can use only those data providers or ODBC drivers, which available by default (program will run on dummy users computers). So I can't use, for example, VFPOLEDB or others providers, which need to be installed. Also, VFPOLEDB, as I understood is only for FoxPro, not for DBase tables.

Comment: Try to use VFPOLEDB provider.

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't work. Error: "File must be opened exclusively to convert the Memo file" I suppose, this provider is for FoxPro tables, not DBase tables. ConnectionString='Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=%s; Collating Sequence=machine;' Also this provider must be installed on client computer and this is impossible. I can use only those providers, which available by default.